# Android - Problem with <provider> INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android

I'm using different Flavours in my project and i had to use some code to save pictures in my internal storage.

The documentation/link i read says that i have to put this in my android manifest:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.q4tech.magazine.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

It works perfectly. I can save the pictures with no problem BUT now i cant install others flavors in my phone because of this error:

> 10/10 15:46:45: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G9650.
>   Installation did not succeed.
>   The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
>   Installation failed due to: 'null'
>   Retry

I don't know what else to do. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: i am facing the same issue in my case i used `com.freshdesk.helpdesk.provider` this and 
i set this line in provider tag `android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.freshdesk.helpdesk.provider"` still facing the same issue note:-  with flavours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your flavors have various package names? If yes, they will get installed without uninstalling the previous flavor. All of the flavors will try to register a `Provider` with the same authority (`com.q4tech.magazine.fileprovider` in your case).

Uninstalling the previous flavor should solve the problem. However, if you want to have multiple flavors simultaneously installed on a single device, you can make the `authorities` package-specific, like this:

```
<provider
...
android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"/>
```

Comment: Which one is correct this `android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"` OR this `android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.q4tech.magazine.fileprovider"`?

Comment: @Arbaz.in both should work fine, so it's up to you which one to choose. The important thing, in this case, is to use the `${applicationId}` because it is different across the flavors.

Comment: Actully issue with my hard coded packeg in some class file 
thanks for the response